# How to set CCLayer size in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I used `setContentSize` but it doesn't work. And I don't want to scale stuff in the layer so I won't use `setScale`.

What should I do?

Comment: `setContentSize` method does not scale your layer.

Answer (score 2):

setContentSize should work as the following. How did you do that?

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/samples/Cpp/TestCpp/Classes/LayerTest/LayerTest.cpp#L841

```
CCLayerGradient* layer1 = CCLayerGradient::create(ccc4(255, 0, 0, 255), ccc4(255, 0, 255, 255));
layer1->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(80, 80));
```

**EDITED**

So you mean you want to clip the image by the content size of the layer? Try to use `CCClippingNode` or [this glScissor node example](https://gist.github.com/l4u/2233073).

Comment: Yes, I did that and it doesn't work. I added an image sprite in the layer which is 200x200, but after I used `this->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(80,80))`, the image still fully displayed.

Comment: but you don't want to use setScale?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try! this it works for me.


CCSize screenSize   = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    float x = screenSize.width;
    float y = screenSize.height;
    CCLayer* layer = new MyLayer();

    float layerX = layer->getContentSize().width;
    float layerY= layer->getContentSize().height;

    float scaleX   = x/layerX;
    float scaleY   = y/layerY;
    layer->setScaleX(scaleX*1.2f);
    layer->setScaleY(scaleY*1.2f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```cpp
auto layerInstance = LayerColor::create();
auto layerInstanceSize = layerInstance->getContentSize();
float layerInstanceSizeWidth = layerInstanceSize.width;
float layerInstanceSizeHeight = layerInstanceSize.height;
```